# Calculate Age from the start of the current Month

Tags: mysql, date, date-difference

I have the following code to calculate a persons date of birth from todays date which works well

```
    SELECT application.applicationLastName, application.applicationFirstName, application.applicationDoB, 
ROUND(DATEDIFF(NOW(), applicationDoB) / 365.2425,1) AS age, application.applicationID, application.applicationAcknowledged, application.applicationContacted, application.applicationDate
FROM application
ORDER BY application.applicationDate ASC
```

However I have been asked to caluclate their age from the 1st of the current month and have tried

```
SELECT application.applicationLastName, application.applicationFirstName, application.applicationDoB, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AS CURMONTH, 
ROUND(DATEDIFF(CURMONTH(), applicationDoB) / 365.2425,1) AS age, application.applicationID, application.applicationAcknowledged, application.applicationContacted, application.applicationDate
FROM application
ORDER BY application.applicationDate ASC
```

However I get the following error: Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `CURMONTH()`. Instead format todays date as 1st of this month.

Use following query:

```
SELECT application.applicationLastName, application.applicationFirstName, application.applicationDoB, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AS CURMONTH, 
ROUND(DATEDIFF(DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01'), applicationDoB) / 365.2425,1) AS age, application.applicationID, application.applicationAcknowledged, application.applicationContacted, application.applicationDate
FROM application
ORDER BY application.applicationDate ASC
```

Comment: I get the following error: Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'

Comment: I used your solution but removed the extra (DATEDIFF that wasnt required

Comment: The final code used:

SELECT application.applicationLastName, application.applicationFirstName, application.applicationDoB,
ROUND(DATEDIFF(DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01'), applicationDoB) / 365.2425,1) AS age, application.applicationID, application.applicationDate
FROM application
ORDER BY application.applicationDate ASC

Answer (score 0):

You're using :
DATEDIFF(CURMONTH(), applicationDoB)

in your code. But CURMONTH() gives you only the month of current date, and applicationDoB gives you a full date. You need to replace CURMONTH() by an expression which correspond to a full date too ( the 1rst of the current month).